# Type annotation for Callable that takes **kwargs

Tags: python, typing

There is a function (***f***) which consumes a function signature (***g***) that takes a known first set of arguments and any number of keyword arguments `**kwargs`. Is there a way to include the `**kwargs` in the type signature of (***g***) that is described in (***f***)?

For example:

```
from typing import Callable, Any
from functools import wraps
import math


def comparator(f: Callable[[Any, Any], bool]) -> Callable[[str], bool]:
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(input_string: str, **kwargs) -> bool:
        a, b, *_ = input_string.split(" ")
        return f(eval(a), eval(b), **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@comparator
def equal(a, b):
    return a == b


@comparator
def equal_within(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    return math.isclose(a, b, rel_tol=rel_tol, abs_tol=abs_tol)


# All following statements should print `True`
print(equal("1 1") == True)
print(equal("1 2") == False)
print(equal_within("5.0 4.99998", rel_tol=1e-5) == True)
print(equal_within("5.0 4.99998") == False)
```

The function `comparator` wraps its argument `f` with `wrapper`, which consumes the input for `f` as a string, parses it and evaluates it using `f`. In this case, Pycharm gives a warning that `return f(eval(a), eval(b), **kwargs)` calls `f` with the unexpected argument `**kwargs`, which doesn't match the expected signature.

[This post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/cn9om2/ew8c3z2/) suggests adding either `Any` or `...` to the type signature of `f` like

- `f: Callable[[Any, Any, ...], bool]`
- `f: Callable[[Any, Any, Any], bool]`

The former causes a TypeError [1], while the latter seems to misleading, since `f` accepts *at least* 2 arguments, rather than exactly 3.

Another workaround is to leave the `Callable` args definition open with `...` like `f: Callable[..., bool]`, but I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate solution.

1. `TypeError: Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type. Got Ellipsis.`

Comment: Based on these two github issues [1](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876) and [2](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876) it appears that this isn't covered by the current `Callable` spec.

Comment: I accidentally linked the same issue twice. The intended second issue was [this](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/264)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

tl;dr: [`Protocol`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) may be the closest feature that's implemented, but it's still not sufficient for what you need. See [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876) for details.

---

**Full answer:**

I think the closest feature to what you're asking for is [`Protocol`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html), which was introduced in Python 3.8 (and backported to older Pythons via [`typing_extensions`](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions)). It allows you to define a `Protocol` subclass that describes the behaviors of the type, pretty much like an "interface" or "trait" in other languages. For functions, a similar syntax is supported:

```py
from typing import Protocol
# from typing_extensions import Protocol  # if you're using Python 3.6

class MyFunction(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: Any, b: Any, **kwargs) -> bool: ...

def decorator(func: MyFunction):
    ...

@decorator  # this type-checks
def my_function(a, b, **kwargs) -> bool:
    return a == b
```

In this case, any function that have a matching signature can match the `MyFunction` type.

However, this is not sufficient for your requirements. In order for the function signatures to match, the function must be able to accept **an arbitrary number of keyword arguments** (i.e., have a `**kwargs` argument). To this point, there's still no way of specifying that the function may (optionally) take any keyword arguments. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876) discusses some possible (albeit verbose or complicated) solutions under the current restrictions.

---

For now, I would suggest just using `Callable[..., bool]` as the type annotation for `f`. It is possible, though, to use `Protocol` to refine the return type of the wrapper:

```py
class ReturnFunc(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, s: str, **kwargs) -> bool: ...

def comparator(f: Callable[..., bool]) -> ReturnFunc:
    ....
```

This gets rid of the "unexpected keyword argument" error at `equal_within("5.0 4.99998", rel_tol=1e-5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This is what I gathered from both that github issue and [this other one](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/264). Guido closed the discussion, saying that Protocol is the way to go.

Comment: A minor edit: Protocol was added in **3.8**, not 3.7: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol

Answer (score 5):

With [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) in Python 3.10, you may try the following solution:

```py
from typing import Callable, Any, ParamSpec, Concatenate
from functools import wraps

P = ParamSpec("P")


def comparator(f: Callable[Concatenate[Any, Any, P], bool]) -> Callable[Concatenate[str, P], bool]:
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(input_string: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> bool:
        a, b, *_ = input_string.split(" ")
        return f(eval(a), eval(b), *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

However it seems that you cannot get rid of `*args: P.args` (which you actually don't need) as PEP 612 requires `P.args` and `P.kwargs` to be used together. If you can make sure that your decorated functions (e.g. `equal` and `equal_within`) do not take extra positional arguments, any attempts to call the functions with extra positional arguments should be rejected by the type checker.

Comment: What about ParamSpecKwargs ? ins't this specifically for this usecase

Comment: @ikamen, yes. To my knowledge that is exactly what that would be for. So `from typing import ParamSpecKwargs` should suffice.